# Issues Closing Windows Form and Cancelling Background Worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I am using a background worker to analyze serial port data on a pop-up Windows form in my application. As part of error-proofing my application I want to be able to stop/cancel the test script if the user tries to close the form during operation. Currently I have my backgroundworker setup as follows:

```
private void backgroundworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    LogMsg(LogMsgType.Normal, "Test Started");
    // execute test script
}
```

If I try to close the form I get a "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created" exception at my `LogMsg()` portion of code:

```
public void LogMsg(LogMsgType msgtype, string msgIn)
{
    rtbAssignSATest.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
    {
        rtbAssignSATest.SelectedText = string.Empty;
        rtbAssignSATest.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
        rtbAssignSATest.SelectionColor = _mainForm.LogMsgTypeColor[(int)msgtype];
        rtbAssignSATest.AppendText(msgIn);
        rtbAssignSATest.ScrollToCaret();
    }));
}
```

With this in mind I evaluated other posts on StackOverflow on how to cancel a thread when closing a windows form. In doing so I came across a portion of code that I have incorporated into my application (see below).

```
volatile bool mClosePending = false;
volatile bool mCompleted = false;

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    mCompleted = true;
    if (mClosePending)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!mCompleted)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        this.Enabled = false;
        e.Cancel = true;
        mClosePending = true;
        return;
    }

    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

Even after incorporating this code I am still seeing the error at the `LogMsg()` portion of code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where your `LogMsg` method is called when you close your form... Can you post that part of your code?

Comment: The `LogMsg` method is used in the core of my text script. On closing I do call a `MessageBox` as follows:

Comment: DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your file before closing the window?", "Save File Reminder", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

Answer (score 1):

Let the base.OnFormClosing(e) to execute even after you set the e.Cancel = true. I think this will work.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
e.Cancel = !mCompleted;
base.OnFormClosing(e)
    if (!mCompleted)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        this.Enabled = false;
        mClosePending = true;

    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you put your

```
base.OnFormClosing(e);
```

line at the top of the method? Just in case it is overwriting your

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

Edit, also, instead of using `volatile`, why don't you use

```
lock (this) {}
```

When do you start the background worker? It could be before the controls on the `Form` have been loaded - this would explain the error message...

Comment: it can't be overwriting it since he calls return at the end of the `if` scope

Comment: @ppetrov, right. my bad. i should go home now, and get some rest!